# arrayList only updated inside onCompletelistener and not outside it

Tags: java, android, arraylist, scope

I am trying to read the data that i have in my cloud firestore and to put it in an array called "urlList". The arrayList is in the onComplete and if i log the array there, it works(it's filled with the data it's suppose to have). Whenever i log the arrayList outside the onComplete, the array is empty. The problem seems to be with the onCompletelistener but i can't find what is going wrong / how to avoid the problem. I added the log of the number 5 and 6 to check where the problem is, and the log in the onCreate does see the 5, but not the 6

```
 public static ArrayList<String> urlList = new ArrayList<String>();
 public static ArrayList<String> groupList = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_middel_scherm);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    ConstraintLayout layout = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.imageLayout);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    CurrentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() == null) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MiddelScherm.this, LoginScherm.class));
            }
        }
    };
    ivImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivImage);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            SelectImage();

        }
    });

    databaseDownload();
    Log.d(TAG, "egregergegre");
    Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(urlList));
    Log.d(TAG, "egregergegre");
    showEachImage(layout);
}

public void showEachImage(ConstraintLayout layout) {
    for (String element: urlList) {
        ImageView image = new ImageView(this);
        image.setLayoutParams(new android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams(80,60));
        image.setMaxHeight(20);
        image.setMaxWidth(20);
        Picasso.get().load(element).into(image);
        layout.addView(image);

    }
}

public void databaseDownload() {
    urlList.add("5");
    db.collection("user").document(CurrentUser).collection("meta-data")
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        urlList.add("6");
                        for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                            String imageValue = document.getString("URL");
                            urlList.add(imageValue);
                            Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(urlList));
                        }
                    } else {
                        Log.w(TAG, "Error getting documents.", task.getException());
                    }
                }
            });

    db.collection("user").document(CurrentUser).collection("Group")
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                            String groupValue = document.getString("Group");
                            groupList.add(groupValue);
                            Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(groupList));
                        }
                    } else {
                        Log.w(TAG, "Error getting documents.", task.getException());
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

I even tried to put the public void showEachImage(ConstraintLayout layout) inside the onCompletelistener but it gave an error at "this" at the line of: ImageView image = new ImageView(this): So i gave up on this structure as well

```
    public void databaseDownload() {
urlList.add("5");
db.collection("user").document(CurrentUser).collection("meta-data")
        .get()
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    urlList.add("6");
                    for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                        String imageValue = document.getString("URL");
                        ImageView image = new ImageView(this);
                        image.setLayoutParams(new 
                        android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams(80,60));
                        image.setMaxHeight(20);
                        image.setMaxWidth(20);
                        Picasso.get().load(imageValue).into(image);
                        layout.addView(image);
                        Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(urlList));
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.w(TAG, "Error getting documents.", task.getException());
                }
            }
        });

db.collection("user").document(CurrentUser).collection("Group")
        .get()
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                        String groupValue = document.getString("Group");
                        groupList.add(groupValue);
                        Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(groupList));
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.w(TAG, "Error getting documents.", task.getException());
                }
            }
        });
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're adding an `OnCompleteListener` is that `get()` starts an **asynchronous** `Task`, which will call the `onComplete()` method when the query is done.

The `get()` method returns *immediately*, which means the query isn't done yet, and hence the `onCreate()` method won't see any data.

Any code that needs the data should be execute in/from the `onComplete()` method.

Comment: Thanks for answering! Would there be a way to avoid using the onCompletelistener? For instance, just leave it out. I have to use the data from both collections in the same class so that won't work due to the code not being in the oncomplete method

Comment: @Eruditee See [Firebase Android: How to read from different references sequentially](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37215071/5221149)

Answer (score 0):

I think crush with ImageView happens because "this" is OnCompleteListener class in onComplete method.