# Child value = null

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a database that looks like this:

```
database
   |
  places
     |
     user1
     |  |___indoors: "yes"
     |  |___outdoors: "yes"
     |
     user2
        |___indoors: "yes"   
        |___outdoors: "no"
```

When I do the following, I get all users places information as a single object (converted to String) with no problems:

```
ValueEventListener placesListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String locations = dataSnapshot.toString(); // I get the entire tree as String
    }
}

//this is how I set the listener to changes
DatabaseReference database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference reference = database.child("places");
reference.addValueEventListener(placesListener);
```

But, when I want only the `indoors` children, I get `DataSnapshot {key = indoors, value = null}`.

This is how I try to get only the `indoors` keys and values (almost the same, only adding extra `.child("indoors")`:

```
ValueEventListener placesListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String indoors = dataSnapshot.child("indoors").toString(); // I get value = null
    }
}

// listener remains the same
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data contained in a `DataSnapshot` is relative, like a [JSON tree](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data#how_data_is_structured_its_a_json_tree). From the documentation on [`DataSnapshot#child()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot.html#child(java.lang.String)):

> Get a DataSnapshot for the location at the specified relative path. The relative path can either be a simple child key (e.g. 'fred') or a deeper slash-separated path (e.g. 'fred/name/first'). If the child location has no data, an empty DataSnapshot is returned.

In your example, there is no child named `indoors` directly under the `places` node. Instead, you have 2 children named `user1` and `user2` which each have a child named `indoors`. Therefore, in order to access one of the `indoors` children, you'll need to do something like:

```
dataSnapshot.child("user1").child("indoors").toString();
```

Alternatively, you can [iterate through the children](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events) using:

```
for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
    Log.d(childSnapshot.getKey() + ": indoors=" + childSnapshot.child("indoors").toString());
}
```

Comment: Thank you. By the way, is there a way to retrieve data from the Firebase database NOT in real time? I just want a specific value but get it now, and not in real time

Comment: Glad to help. Do you mean synchronously? Not exactly, as this isn't a supported feature of Firebase, but there are options, see [Is it possible to synchronously load data from Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31700830) for more details.