# Android: Get data synchronously in main Thread from Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: android, multithreading, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm having hard times with building my app that uses Firebase Realtime Database.

**What I want to achieve:**

I have two tables:

[GuessedSongsTable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/an5U6.jpg)

[SongsTable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozuJt.jpg)

I want to get 10 songs that have not been guessed by current User yet.

I thought about method similar to that (**pseudo-code**) running in my Activity:

```
public List<SongPOJO> getTenUniqueSongs() {
    List<SongPOJO> myList = new ArrayList<>();
    int songId = 0;

    while(myList.size() < 10) {

        SongPOJO mySong = getASongFromTheDatabase(songId);

        if (!checkIfSongExistsInTableGuessedSongs())
            myList.add(mySong);

        ++songId;
    }
}
```

I know how to write request to the Realtime database's reference (get dataSnapshot and check if dataSnapshot exists using exists() method). But that's not the case.

The problem is that I want to get this data **synchronously in the main Thread** (I will give the user some kind of waiting alert until this operation finishes successfully). But I don't know how to do that.

I've done some research and I was trying to implement this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45308259/5834189 using TaskCompletionSource . But the thing is it cannot be run in the main Thread. I know I can handle this using AsyncTask but I have no idea how to get the data synchronously.

I completely understand that working with the database means making asynchronous calls, but how to get data in a specific moment?

Could you please help me with finding the solution? Multithreading seems to be really mysterious to me at the moment.

Comment: There is no way to retrieve data synchronously with the Firebase SDK. You could retrieve the data using the REST API and make that a blocking call, but I doubt you want to do that either. It sounds more like you want to show a "please wait" indicator, that you then hide once the data has loaded.

Comment: Why don't you use asyntask to get the data, and just call asynTaskObj.get() inside your UI thread? The get() method will block until asynctask finishes.

Comment: @Steven The Firebase Database client, already runs all network operations in a background thread. This means that all operations take place without blocking your main thread. Putting it in an AsyncTask does not give any additional benefits. If you are using `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`, you can override the `onDataChanged()` method and hide the `ProgressBar` inside it.

Comment: @Alex Mamo Ah I see. I haven't used Firebase myself yet. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @Steven You're welcome.

Comment: But can't I do it somehow using Callable and Future?