# ItemkeyedDataSource.LoadInitialCallback onResult() did not do anything

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore, pagedlist

**Problem**:
The observer on `LiveData<PagedList>` is not triggered after the `ItemKeyedDataSource.LoadedInitialCallback.onResult()` is called.

At the time `callback.onResult(...)`, the value passed in is correct.
However, nothing happens after that.

**Expected**: After `callback.onResult(...)`, the observer should be able to detect there is a change to LiveData.

**Relevant Code**:
Method for fetching data from network (It's in a class called CommentManager), here we used Firestore:

```
...
public void loadInitialComments(int pageSize,
                                ItemKeyedDataSource.LoadInitialCallback<Comment> callback) {
    collectionReference.orderBy(DatabaseConstants.FIELD_TIMESTAMP)
        .limit(pageSize)
        .get()
        .addOnSuccessListener(queryDocumentSnapshots -> {
            callback.onResult(getComments(queryDocumentSnapshots));
        });
}
...
```

How the function is being called in DataSource class

```
...
@Override
public void loadInitial(LoadInitialParams<String> params,
                        LoadInitialCallback<Comment> callback) {
    commentManager.loadInitialComments(params.requestedLoadSize, callback);
}
...
```

ViewModel class

```
public final class CommentViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private final LiveData<PagedList<Comment>> comments;

    public CommentViewModel() {
        comments = new LivePagedListBuilder<>(new CommentDataSourceFactory(new CommentManager()), config).build();
    }

    public LiveData<PagedList<Comment>> getComments() {
        return comments;
    }
```

How ViewModel is called in main activity

```
...
CommentViewModel commentViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this,
    new CommentViewModelFactory())
    .get(CommentViewModel.class);
commentViewModel.getComments().observe(this, comments -> commentListAdapter.submitList(comments));
...
```

Comment: I had a similar issue, for some reason in loadIntial asynchronous method doesn't work. you've to fetch the data synchronously at least for the loadInitial.

Comment: I see.
1. How do you do a synchronous data fetch on Firestore?
2. Is this the case only for loadInitial not for loadAfter and loadBefore?

Comment: Try from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31700830/is-it-possible-to-synchronously-load-data-from-firebase

Comment: Thank you very much! I am able to do the synchronous data fetch. Now code in my DataSource class loadInitial method, I changed it to
`List<Comment> comments = commentManager.loadInitialComments(params.requestedLoadSize); callback.onResult(comments);`
However, still nothing happens after `callback.onResult(comments)`

Comment: Have you tried debugging through out every step? Maybe put some logs in each step and check what values are you getting.

Comment: Also looks like you're trying to implement paging, check this article to get some hints:
https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-paging-library-tutorial/

Comment: The information I found during debugging: 
1. the `getComment()` method in ViewModel class is called, at that time it returns null; 2. `loadInitial` in DataSource is called; 3. `loadInitial` in CommentManager is called and returned the correct values; 4. `callback.onResult()` is called and it's with the correct values; 5. The application continues and nothing happens.

Thanks for the information provided. For the tutorial, it's with Retrofit, which I think is used for REST API. I haven't used Firestore REST API before, which might require major changes. Is that a more recommended approach?

Comment: No, don't use Retrofit, just see the structure of paging used in the library, like DataSourceFactoryClass and it's implementation in the ViewModel