# Firebase Android error: Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, mobile

I'm getting this error when i create new user on firebase from my sign-up form :

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child()

I search about this error on google and on YouTube but i don't found something for my program.

Here is a part of my code on SignUpActivity.java:

```
    final EditText email = findViewById(R.id.email_address);
    final EditText display_name = findViewById(R.id.display_name);
    final EditText password = findViewById(R.id.pass_sign_up);
    final EditText comfirm_pass = findViewById(R.id.comfirm_pass);
    final Button submit = findViewById(R.id.submit_btn_signup);
    final TextView signin = findViewById(R.id.textView8);
    final FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    final String[] error = new String[1];
    final ProgressBar loading_icon = findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);


    // hide loading icon \\
    loading_icon.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    signin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(SignupActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            loading_icon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            String email_input = email.getText().toString();
            String display_name_input = display_name.getText().toString();
            String password_input = password.getText().toString();
            String comfirm_pass_input = comfirm_pass.getText().toString();

            if (email_input.isEmpty() || display_name_input.isEmpty() || password_input.isEmpty() || comfirm_pass_input.isEmpty()){
                error[0] = "Please fill all the values and try again";
                Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, error[0], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                loading_icon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }else{
                if (!password_input.equals(comfirm_pass_input)){
                    error[0] = "passwords do not match";
                    Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, error[0], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    loading_icon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }else{
                    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email_input,password_input).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull @NotNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()){
                                finish();
                                // set display name for user \\
                                FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                                UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdates = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
                                        .setDisplayName(display_name_input).build();
                                user.updateProfile(profileUpdates);

                                DatabaseReference mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

                                mRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(){
                                    @Override
                                    public void onDataChange(@NotNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){

                                        // Get the max_user_id to set the main user id and create the user on Firebase real-time DB \\
                                        String maxUserId = dataSnapshot.child("max_user_id").getValue().toString();
                                        int maxUserIdToInt = Integer.parseInt(maxUserId);
                                        int userId = maxUserIdToInt+1;
                                        newUserId = String.valueOf(userId);
                                        mRef.child("users").child(newUserId).child("name").setValue(display_name_input);
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onCancelled(@NotNull DatabaseError databaseError){
                                        Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this,"error: " + databaseError, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }
                                });

                                mRef.child("users").child(newUserId);
                                

                                Intent intent = new Intent(SignupActivity.this,HomeActivity.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }else{
                                loading_icon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                error[0] = "failed to sign up, the email address aleready exist or the password lenght is lower than 6 characters";
                                Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, error[0], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    });

}
```

}

NOTE: i'm beginner on firebase for android applications. Also i created today my account here and stackoverflow is so cool and helpfull

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the last line in this fragment:

```
DatabaseReference mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

mRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(){
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NotNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){

        // Get the max_user_id to set the main user id and create the user on Firebase real-time DB \\
        String maxUserId = dataSnapshot.child("max_user_id").getValue().toString();
        int maxUserIdToInt = Integer.parseInt(maxUserId);
        int userId = maxUserIdToInt+1;
        newUserId = String.valueOf(userId);
        mRef.child("users").child(newUserId).child("name").setValue(display_name_input);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NotNull DatabaseError databaseError){
        Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this,"error: " + databaseError, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});

mRef.child("users").child(newUserId);
```

That line does nothing meaningful, but it executes before `newUserId = String.valueOf(userId)`, which means you're passing in an initialized `newUserId` and that causes the error messages.

Since this line `mRef.child("users").child(newUserId);` does nothing anyway, you can safely remove it.

As a general rule: you should only use the `newUserId` inside the `onDataChange` or in code that is called from there. For this reason, I recommend making it a local variable in `onDataChange` instead of a field or otherwise broader scope. For more on why this is, see [Is it possible to synchronously load data from Firebase?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31700830/synchronous-blocking-operation/31702957) and [Setting Singleton property value in Firebase Listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33203379/setting-singleton-property-value-in-firebase-listener).

Comment: if I understood correctly you mean to take the variables out of the method and leave only the variable newUserId and remove and the line when i adding the variable inside in Firebase db. But i add this line because I thought when you can add a variable on db with this method but maybe I'm wrong. So how i can create a new user inside real-time db??. Thanks

Comment: Data is only written once you call `setValue`, which you are doing inside `onDataChange` where `newUserId` **is** initialized (as far as I can tell). If you put a breakpoint on `mRef.child("users").child(newUserId);` and run the app in a debugger, you'll see that `newUserId` doesn't have a value, as the `onDataChange` hasn't been run yet. Please read the links I provided in my answer, as I explained it in more detail there.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `child()`, you need to pass a non-null String as the parameter. In your case,  `newUserId` is null for some reason. Hence you call `child(newUserId)`, Firebase throws an exception.

The way forward should be check if the way you are accessing child with path `max_user_id` is correct or not. You can keep a breakpoint at that location and then go through the structure of `dataSnapshot` to get the correct path.

Comment: i have write a variable in database with this name and i try to get the value of it on int from string and maybe there is a problem with the convert from string to int. That's why is null maybe