# Return Custom ArrayList from onSuccessListener in firebase android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am writing a function which gets all URLs of Images uploaded to FirebaseStorage,next I deseralize and populate a custom ArrayList which I return to required class through callback.
But onSuccess being Asynchronous, ArrayList is always null.

```
public static void getAllQuestions(MyCallback callback, String path){
        MyCallback myCallback=callback;
        ArrayList<AddQuestion> q=new ArrayList<>();
        FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child(path).listAll()
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<ListResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(ListResult listResult) {

                        for (StorageReference item : listResult.getItems()) {
                            // All the items under listRef.
                            item.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                    AddQuestion addQuestion=new AddQuestion(uri.toString(),
                                            Utility.removeExtension(item.getName()));
                                    q.add(addQuestion);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        if(q!=null){
                            Log.e("notnull",q.toString());
                            myCallback.loadAllQuestions(q);
                        }


                    }

                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
                    }
                });
    }
```

Here q turns null.

Comment: "Here q returns null." I'm not sure I understand what this means. Nothing in your code returns `q` as far as I can see. Can you edit your question to clarify, for example by adding a line that logs the `null` value and including the updated code and its output in your question?

Comment: You might check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48499310/how-to-return-a-documentsnapshot-as-a-result-of-a-method/48500679#48500679).

Comment: That doesn't help at all. Please see [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as it is impossible to say at this point what is going wrong for you. Alex' guess is not bad though, so I'd check out his link and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31700830/synchronous-blocking-operation/31702957 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33203379/setting-singleton-property-value-in-firebase-listener too